# Pass List back to spring controller from jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have two methods in spring controller class. First method will create a list and pass it to the Jsp page. I want to access that list in second method of controller. but getting null

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ModelAndView loadNames(@ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm, BindingResult result, Model model) throws Exception {
 
 
     List<String> names = createList();
     
     employeeForm.setNameList(names);
     model.addAttribute("nameList", names);
     return new ModelAndView("empjsp", "employeeForm", employeeForm);
 }
 
 
     <form:form name="employeeForm" modelAttribute="employeeForm" methos="POST">
       <form:select path="empName" id="empName">
                  <form:option value="0" label="----Select-----" />
                  <c:forEach items="${employeeForm.nameList}" var="name">
                       <form:option value="${name}" label="${name}" />
                   </c:forEach>    
                 </form:select>
 
 
  After selecting the required data from jsp, I will do javascript action submission;
 
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/listJspData", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ModelAndView loadJspData(@ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm, BindingResult result, Model model) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("-----------Enter---------------"+employeeForm.getNameList());
            System.out.println("-----------Enter---------------"+model.getAttribute("nameList"));
 
 }
```

Both System out println are null

Comment: Maybe something like this - https://www.viralpatel.net/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/